# Не могу прочитать голос с микрофона. Выдаёт ошибку OSError: [Errno -9999] Unanticipated host error

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-речи

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone(device_index = 0) as source:
    print('Скажите что-нибудь...')
    audio = r.listen(source)

query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
print('Вы Сказали; ' + query.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны включить доступ к микрофону
Параметры -> Конфиденциальность -> Микрофон
Далее как на скрине(галочка на доступ к микрофону для этого устройства и разрешить приложениям доступ к микрофону)
[image: Тут]